WMTS GetCapabilities lists http URLs not HTTPS
I have a web app using the ESRI JS Maps SDK and I get a CORS error when it is loading the WMTSLayer that is being built from a geoserver wmts url. I think the WmtsLayer is getting the URL from the GetCapabilities xml and for some reason in the GetCapabilities it is not using HTTPS for the URLs. All the other layer preview links from the GeoServer web admin use HTTPS. I don't understand why or how to fix the issue.

CORS is probably not related to Https, you need to set it up on your servlet engine. The URLs in the capabilities document are controlled via the proxy URL setting in the global settings page.

@IanTurton We just upgraded to 2.25.2 and now I am getting a 403 error when trying to save the proxy base url. You don't have auth to view this page.

Well you probably need to fix that first
